# Read dbf file encoded in windows-1252 (CP1252) in RStudio on Mac OS

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio, windows-1252

I'm trying to use R to read some dbf files into an R data frame, problem is, one of the columns is encoded in windows-1252, I know I can use Sys.setlocale() to change to the right encoding but when I try using:

> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "windows-1252")
>   [1] ""
>   Warning message:
>   In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "windows-1252") :
>     OS reports request to set locale to "windows-1252" cannot be honored

If I read it just like that, the accents read (this is mexican data in spanish from INEGI) get all messed up.

I tried using:

Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "es_ES.ISO8859-1")
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "es_ES.ISO8859-1")

but when I see the head in the console it reads:

"Poblaci�n de 0 a 2 a�os"

instead of:

"Población de 0 a 2 años"

but if I use View() to read that file, the accents are OK.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to read a DBF:
You may try:

```
  Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Spanish_Mexico.1252")
```

If it's WIN 1252 it should work...
Or go to Tools>Global_Options> Change encoding